# Virtual machine or bootcamp for ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, mac, osx, viewshed, virtual-machine

I want to use ArcGIS for viewshed analysis on a Mac. Would virtual machine software such as Parallels or VMware Fusion be powerful enough for viewshed analysis compared with bootcamp?

Comment: I've known plenty of people to run ArcGIS on a Mac using Parallels and VM Ware. Also, I'd point out that there are GIS that are capable of running on Macs without using Parallels that will let you do viewshed analysis. Good luck.

Comment: This is opinion-based. That being said My opinion, having tried both, is that Bootcamp is a better overall experience.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I have just found that it is possible to use bootcamp to begin with and then use Parallels or VMware to virtualise the boot camped partition?